# Tabular layout of content without using a float

Tags: css

This code is layed out in 1 column.  I want to get a tabular 2 column layout.

```
<span id="col1">
  <div>Filter by</div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="hello" />
  </div>
</span>
<span id="col2">
  <div>Search</div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="hello" />
  </div>
</span>
```

How can I achieve this without using float?

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b8amy4mv/3/)

Comment: Would `display:inline-block` suffice? [Example here](https://jsfiddle.net/b8amy4mv/4/). I have the feeling you're looking for a more complex solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the flexbox for that:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="col1">
    <div>Filter by</div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="hello" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="col2">
    <div>Search</div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" value="hello" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Note that I changed your `span` to `div` elements (since span are inline and should not contain block elements).
I also wrapped the entire block with `div.container` so I'll be able to set that container as the flexbox.

Comment: I saw flex, but I did not know how to apply it correctly.  This is exactly what I needed

Comment: You are welcome! An upvote will be appreciated as well :)

Comment: Already did and marked as answer.  Despite the fact this is marked as a duplicate, you helped me figure out how to use the answers in the other question correctly.

Comment: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want the columns to be able to be shown/hidden, you could do this:

```
<head>
<script>
$('.next').click(function() {
 var next = $('.col').next();
 var curr = $('.col');

 next.addClass('col-active');
 curr.removeClass('col-active');
});
</script>
<style>
.col {
display: none;
}

.col-active {
display: block !important;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span id="col1" class="col col-active">
  <div>Filter by</div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="hello" />
  </div>
</span>
<span id="col2" class="col">
  <div>Search</div>
  <div>
    <input type="text" value="hello" />
  </div>
</span>

<a class="next">Next Page</a>
</body>
```

This essentially shows and hides the columns based on the `<a>` being clicked. I use this quite a lot when having sliders/tabulated pages.

Hope this helps :)